# SQL query on SUM function plus JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Sorry if this has been covered before but I couldnt find an example to my issue

Situation: Say I have a table of sales and want to display them

Step 1)

```
SELECT payment_id, amount, payment_date
FROM payment
WHERE payment_date >= '2018-01-01' 
AND payment_date <= NOW());
```

Now I want to sum sales or 'amount
Step 2)

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as 'Total Amount'
FROM
(SELECT payment_id, amount, payment_date
FROM payment
WHERE payment_date >= '2018-01-01' 
AND payment_date <= NOW()
);
```

Is it possible to have that 'total amount' as a new row in my first table? Ie join the list of payment details with a total amount figure at the end of the list?

Comment: Do you have payments in the future?  If not, toss `AND payment_date <= NOW()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand `payment_id` is unique (maybe primary). If so:

```
SELECT payment_id, SUM(amount), payment_date
FROM payment
WHERE payment_date >= '2018-01-01' 
AND payment_date <= NOW())
GROUP BY payment_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

If it is not unique, or if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled:

```
SELECT payment_id, SUM(amount), payment_date
FROM payment
WHERE payment_date >= '2018-01-01' 
AND payment_date <= NOW())
GROUP BY payment_id, payment_date WITH ROLLUP
HAVING payment_date IS NOT NULL or payment_id IS NULL;
```

Last query will give wrong result if `payment_date` can be NULL.

Comment: Thanks that works great! Query works in the way I need it to and so simple in the end. I wasnt familiar with the ROLLUP function previously so thanks for sharing

Comment: ROLLUP is not a function. It is GROUP BY modifier.

Comment: If you had another unique or foreign id such as customer_id how would you adapt the query to include? Would it just be GROUP by payment_id WITH ROLLUP, customer_id

Comment: Group by payment_Id, customer_id WITH ROLLUP.